# Joining list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, join, merge

I have the two lists (simple toy example)

```
X = list(A=list(a=1,b=2),B=list(a=10,b=20))

Y = list(A=list(c=3,d=4),B=list(c=30,d=40))
```

I would like to join them together in a list Z such that

`Z$A = list(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)`

and

`Z$B = list(a=10,b=20,c=30,d=40)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this if i understood you correctly:

**After edit of question:**

```
Z <- mapply(c, X, Y, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

The above will give the same result as mentioned in your question

Comment: Pradeep sorry my example was wrong. Thanks for answering me though.

Comment: No issues , I have changed my answer , hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c(X,Y)  #gives the concatenation
list(X,Y) #gives a list of lists
```

Comment: sorry this doesn´t work because my example is not correct (it does, but doesn´t apply to my case).
I update the question